# Autoset height and width of textarea which has div behind

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor, syntax-highlighting

I'm creating a simple code editor with syntax highlighting. The highlighting works like this: I have a textarea whose contents are transparent. Right behind that textarea, there is a div, whose value automatically updates to that of the textarea but with syntax highlighting.

So, right now I'm making a function which resizes the textarea's height and width to show all its contents and also to be in sync with the div.
I tried with this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-code">
    <div id='color-code'></div>
    <textarea id='main-code'></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-code {position: relative; background: hsl(220, 16%, 14%);  width: 80%; overflow: auto;}

#color-code, #main-code {padding: 16px;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap; font-family: monospace; font-size: 16px; line-height: inherit;}

#main-code {position: relative;
  color: transparent; /* Make text invisible */
  caret-color: hsl( 50, 75%, 70%); /* But keep caret visible */ margin-bottom: 20px; }

#main-code:focus {outline: 1px solid hsl(220, 16%, 19%);}
#main-code::selection {background: hsla( 0, 0%, 90%, 0.2);}

#color-code {position: absolute; user-select: none;}
```

JS

```
function auto_grow() {
// Editor is the main textarea, while ColoredEd is the div behind it
   Editor.style.cssText = "height: " + ColoredEd.scrollHeight +"px";
    Editor.style.width = ColoredEd.scrollWidth+"px";
console.log("resized: " + Editor.style.height + "   " + ColoredEd.scrollHeight);
}
```

This code is working, but for some reason even if I type a single character *without creating any new lines*, it increases the height of the editor. This is also causing my editor to lag sometimes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both the `#color-code` and the `#main-code` have the same parent. Maybe it would work if you would gibt the parent `.my-code { position: relative; }` and then place the `#color-code` element using position absolute, something like `#color-code { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; }`. This would make the `color-code` element grown when the textarea also grows...

Comment: @Boguz, tried that, but the problem still persists.